# How can I make a crescent shape?

Tags: java

I want think make a crescent shape, and I was thinking of overlapping a fillArc over another fillArc, but I do not want that because the top layer would not be transparent. Is there any other way?

Comment: Go to your marker board and do it. That will help you visualize it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link out:
[Clipping](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt/ClipShape.html)

(It references an instance of Graphics2D, but Graphics uses the same idea.)

Use `setClip(Shape shape)`with an Ellipse shape. 
The clip area is where graphics will not be drawn after the clip is set. 
Then use a single call of `fillArc(int x, int y, int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle)` to draw your crescent shape.